# Execute a Code Depending on Variable Input

Tags: python, variables

I am creating an Enrollment Management Program as an output for our school.

The program I am creating contains a section that asks the user about their family.

One category is how many siblings they have. I want the program to ask the user for the number of siblings they have, and then execute the siblingCheck function that many times.

I tried this solution but it does not work, it continues to ask the user for the same values over and over again:

```
def siblingCheck():
    input("Name: ")
    input("Age: ")
    input("Grade Level: ")


siblingCount = int(input("Number of Siblings: "))
x = 0
while (x <= siblingCount):
    siblingCheck()
else:
    print("Next Section.")
```

Comment: add x+=1 after siblingCheck() to increment x;  and use x=1 or while(x<siblingCount)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that for any non-negative value of `siblingCount`, `while` loop will run forever. You may want use a `for` loop instead:

```
def siblingCheck():
    input("Name: ")
    input("Age: ")
    input("Grade Level: ")


siblingCount = int(input("Number of Siblings: "))
if siblingCount > 0:
    for i in range(siblingCount):
        siblingCheck()
else:
    print("Next Section.")
```